# Correctly showing RTL languages in JIRA

Tags: jira

Does anybody knows how to use JIRA with RTL languages?

It seems that their interface is not configurable to change the direction of text flow.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is server side Jira plugin for this.
   [Right To Left Plugin for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213663/right-to-left-plugin-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview)
   Thought I did not try it and of cause that means buying, installing etc.
2. There is also a chrome plugin 
   [JiraRTL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jirartl/djnbhcebgngagmioniajfhbldkoegcco)
   (Disclaimer I am the creator of this plugin. And by the way, help wanted for maintaining it.)

Answer (score 0):

I use Jira announcement banner to inject custom CSS or JS: [How to add custom JS and CSS](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-hide-elements-in-jira-using-css-or-javascript-958774526.html)

Just add this code:

```html
<script>
setInterval(function () {
  let pegah_dirAutoSupportSelector =
    ".user-content-block:not([dir])";
  const items = document.querySelectorAll(pegah_dirAutoSupportSelector);
  items.forEach((x) => {
    x.setAttribute("dir", "auto");
  });
}, 1000);
</script>
```